# Couples sleeping in a bed in public view

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, sleep

This question / answer discusses the issue of [**Couple's showing affection in public.**](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55400/couples-showing-affection-in-public)

In regard to that, I was wondering whether it would be permitted / appropriate for a couple to sleep in a bed together, in a place which is view-able to others. For example if there was a double couch/bed in a large living room of a family home, could they host a couple to sleep on that? (No physical endearment will take place, only sleeping).

Comment: Don't husband and wife usually sleep in separate beds unless they're performing their marital duties? I apologize if I'm ignorant, I'm not married and haven't taken a chosson class. *bashful* :)

Comment: @ezra a practice like that is not strictly necessary https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51128/