# kissing in the yichud room

Tags: halacha, marriage, wedding, kissing

After a jewish couple gets married and they go to the yichud room, is the *choson* allowed to **kiss** the *kallah*?

Comment: Why would you think yes or no? Please include the basis of your question (not just here, but in other questions as well).

Comment: In particular, why would you think this situation would be different from any other time in their married life?

Comment: @msh210 You were looking for http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1229/5323, I think.

Comment: related but may be different ]https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25603/5120

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Nit'e Gavriel*, *Nisuin* 1, chapter 37](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46545&st=&pgnum=219), is about the *Yichud* room and he mentions no prohibition on kissing that I see.

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of the yichud room is to provide seclusion of sufficient duration so that the marriage could *technically* be consummated. Traditionally we don't do so, but you certainly could. And kissing is certainly not a problem.

Interesting side note - some traditions invert the order of the yichud room so that instead of taking place after the chuppah, it takes place after the meal (when everyone has pretty much left). The reasoning is that once there is yichud and we consider them fully married, the wife must cover her hair. By shifting it to the end of the wedding feast it allows her to remain with her hair uncovered during the dancing and the meal.

Comment: According to which tradition do we not do so?

Comment: @Chaim I think you're taking that sentence too literally. The bride and groom have been fasting and very busy in the run up to the wedding. the yichud room is their first chance for piece and quiet and a chance to eat. I was merely pointing out that generally they take the opportunity to relax before the dancing, not to consummate their marriage.